# Call child's method from parent in jQuery extended object

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance, javascript-objects

I've got a child Javascript object

```
var child = {
    foo: function() {
        console.log('bar');
    }
};
```

and a parent object

```
var parent = {
    baz: function() {
        this.foo();
    }
};
```

merged with jQuery

```
$.extend(child, parent);
```

I guess why this works

```
child.baz();
// prints 'bar'
```

and this does not

```
$('#btn').click(child.baz);
// Uncaught TypeError: this.foo is not a function
```

Thank you

Comment: `this` is `DOM` element within event handler

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196).

Comment: JS gets really screwy with it's `this` scope. This helped me to understand it if you wish to have a deeper understanding https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the code like this:

```
$('#btn').click(child.baz.bind(child));
```

The reason your code didn't work was that when click handler is called, `this` is set to button whereas you want `this` to be set to `child`.
In javascript  `this` is bound dynamically and is determined by who calls the function. So in first case `child.baz();`, implicit binding rule applies and `this` is set to `child`. Using `bind` will hard bind `this` to `child` in the button click callback case.

```js
var child = {
  foo: function() {
    console.log('bar');
  }
};

var parent = {
  baz: function() {
    this.foo();
  }
};

$.extend(child, parent);

child.baz();
$('#btn').click(child.baz.bind(child));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` is `DOM` element within event handler. You can use [`$.proxy()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy) to set `this` to an object within function call

```js
var child = {
    foo: function() {
        console.log('bar');
    }
};

var parent = {
    baz: function() {
        this.foo();
    }
};

$.extend(child, parent);

$("#btn").click($.proxy(child.baz, child));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="btn">click</div>
```